# After interrupting an iPhone update, can I avoid connecting to iTunes?

Tags: software-update

I was updating my iPhone and I accidentally pressed the home and lock button together thus interrupting the update. It has directed me to a link where I was instructed to connect the iPhone to iTunes and download the update. how can I recover my phone without connecting to itunes?

Comment: What is your phone showing now? Is the phone continuing to ask you connect to iTunes – stopping you doing anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the state of the update it may not be possible to restore. Hold Power and Home until the device reboots. If the device reboots back to the Connect to iTunes screen, then you will have to connect to iTunes and follow the instructions.